# how can I use GUID datatype in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, guid

I want to build an employees table using `SQL SERVER 2008` , and in my table I want to have an ID for each employee .

I heared about **GUID** and I kind of understood that its a data type , But I couldn't use it

could you please show me the way to use it ...

by the way , lets say I want something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
ID guid PRIMARY KEY,
Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

How can I do it ?? because I want to benefit from it , but I couldn't find out how to do that

Answer (score 24):

It's not called GUID in SQL Server. It's called uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 16):

The type is called UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as others have pointed out already. But I think you absolutely must read this article before proceeding: [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)

Comment: +1 great link - GUID as PK is intriguing - but comes at a price!

Answer (score 6):

They are called [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use uniqueidentifier as primary key if clustered (which is the default for PKs)

Seriously: use a standard IDENTITY instead

Comment: I didn't get you well , what do mean by saying , use Identity instead

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What if you want your ID to be globally unique? Can't really think of a reason why you'd want that right now, but i'm interested in knowing why it's such a bad idea?

Comment: @Hugo: See, for example, Kimberly L. Tripp's article: [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx).

Comment: @Hugo Migneron: IDENTITY with bigint would give you 10E38 discrete values. Is that not enough? int give 4 billion. If you need globally unique say for replication, then you use GUID but *not* as a key. As for why, see Remus' answer: a good key is narrow, numeric and strictly monotonically increasing. uniqueidentifier fails on all counts.

Comment: The reason you don't want to use a GUID is related to the clustering index, not necessarily as a unique identifier.  There is no benefit when clustering on a GUID, but the disadvantages can be big.  For example, when you add new rows, you insert into the middle of the data, rather than the end, as with an IDENTITY.  This creates fragmentation, resulting in poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using [NEWSEQUENCIALID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) as the default value for your ID column as it would be faster than using NEWID() generate the GUIDs.

BUT (from the same link above):-

**If privacy is a concern, do not use this function. It is possible to guess the value of the next generated GUID and, therefore, access data associated with that GUID.**

Answer (score 1):

Practical demo, FWIW

```
DECLARE @guid1 AS uniqueidentifier
SET @guid1 = NEWID()
SELECT @guid1
```

Answer (score 0):

The GUID in sql server is known by UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data type. below is the desired code.

```
 CREATE TABLE Employees 
    (
        Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name NVARCHAR (50) not null
    )
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `uniqueidentifier`.
And also if you want to auto-generate this value on insert, you should write `(newid())` into the **Default Value or Binding** setting. Like here:

[image]