# SQL Server UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as a normal column?

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I just came across this question [Using GUID/Uniqueidentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100479/how-can-i-use-guid-datatype-in-sql-server-2008) and one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4100559/5861508) pointed toward an [article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) which basically discuss how bad it is to use GUIDs as primary key.

However, I want to use uniqueidentifiers as a normal column in my tables, instead of PKs, so that a query through api could be obfuscated and not something which people can easily guess and play around my data. So that when  querying a record, let's say

```
www.domain.com/api/v3/device/component/6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF
```

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE guid = '6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF'
```

I can use it, instead of int/bigint identity col.

Is this a bad approach? What might be the overheads of using this approach? Or is there any other alternative? Some tables of my db might be pretty big with hundred of records every 10-15 seconds.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Once the uniqueidentifier is saved, I don't see this being a problem. However, GUID's are relatively expensive to generate.

Comment: I was thinking same, but @gbn below is mentioning some of the expenses comes in package with GUID.

Answer (score 5):

A primary key uniquely identifies a row: it be either clustered or non-clustered

So, a GUID can be a primary key with no problem *if* it is non-clustered.
Or it can be the unique key of another non-clustered unique index.

### Access patterns

Let's assume you have an int identity columns as the clustered index.
Then this will do two table touches

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE guid='6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF'
```

One on the index with guid as key to get the clustering key. Then another touch on the clustered index. This is a "key" lookup and can be expensive sometimes.

You can mitigate this by using INCLUDE on the guid based non-clustered index for the most common queries

### Fragmentation

You can also mitigate the GUID-fragmentation issue by using NEWSEQUENTIALID which gives a strictly monotonically increasing GUID value.

If you have a good maintenance window you can defragment the table with a GUID clustered key every night.

### Width

The width of the GUID (16 bytes) when clustered affects all non-clustered indexes. This matters if you expected several indexes or child tables that would use GUID.

Summary: it is generally bad but this does not always matter

Note, we use GUIDs on the same way you plan for our website and have far greater loads. The GUID column is non-clustered

Comment: Thanks for detail insight @gbn . Fragmentation might not be a good idea for my specific solution, one question though, what do you mean when you are saying using INCLUDE on guid based non-clustered index. can you give a short example,  may be i am not grasping that. 
and how badly it effects the performance on other tables which are not using guid? is it something which is neglectable, as you have experience of facing much greater loads?